# Underline TextField with Leading/Trailing Icons

Tags: swiftui

I have the following `TextFieldStyle` that I use to underline TextFields:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct UnderlineTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding(.bottom, 8)
            .background(
                Rectangle().frame(maxHeight: 1)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            )
    }
}

extension TextFieldStyle where Self == UnderlineTextFieldStyle {
    static var underline: UnderlineTextFieldStyle {
        get { UnderlineTextFieldStyle() }
    }
}
```

```swift
TextField(text: text, prompt: Text(placeholder)) {}
    .textFieldStyle(.underline)
```

[image: Underlined TextField]

Now when I add leading/trailing icons (via overlay or background), I have to add padding so the text doesn't over/underlap the icons. The problem is that the underline doesn't span under the icons:

```swift
TextField(text: text, prompt: Text(placeholder)) {}
    .textFieldStyle(.underline)
    .padding(.leading, 24)
    .padding(.trailing, 38)
    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
        if let systemImage = icon {
            if !systemImage.isEmpty {
                Image(systemName: systemImage)
                    .font(.body.weight(.semibold))

            }
        }
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
        if showHide {
            Button(action: { overrideSecure = true }) {
                Image(systemName: "eye.slash")
                    .font(.body.weight(.semibold))

            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Underline TextField w/ Icons]

How can I add icons and retain a full-width underline?

Comment: You don't have to use overlays. Create a view where on root level you have an `HStack`, place icon, TextField, Button inside it, and have underline attached to HStack instead of .

Comment: You're right. Sometimes it's the simplest of solutions.